# Passing a PHP string and an integer as arguments to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, function, arguments

I am trying to pass a string and an int from PHP as the arguments for a JavaScript function. I tried a lot of different solutions and understand that it has something to do with escape characters. But I can't figure it out, so I hope you can help me.
This line is what is giving me troubles:

```
<button onclick="addToCart(<?php echo $productName ?>, <?php echo $price ?>)">Add to cart</button>
```

If I pass the id for example, there is no problem, so it has to do with the fact that the product name is a string.

Entire Code:

```
    <?php
    $databaseConnection = connectToDatabase();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
    $res = $databaseConnection->query($sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

    if ($count > 0) {
        //products available
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $productName = $row['productName'];
            $imageName = $row['imageName'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $quantity = $row['quantity'];
    ?>
            <!--display all products-->
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="img/<?php echo $imageName; ?>">
                <h4><?php echo $productName; ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo $price; ?> kr</p>
                <p style="color: green"><?php echo $quantity; ?> left in stock</p>
                <button onclick="addToCart(<?php echo $productName ?>, <?php echo $price ?>)">Add to cart</button>

            </div>
    <?php

        }
    }

    ?>
```

The function is in it is own .js file, and works if I pass to ints instead of strings.

```
function addToCart(x,y) {
    alert(x + y);
}
```

Comment: Quote the string.

Comment: Yeah, I do not know how to do that. I tried stuff like this, which didn't work:
<button onclick="addToCart(<?php echo \"$productName\" ?>, <?php echo $price ?>)">Add to cart</button>

Comment: Not in PHP. Before and after the PHP tags, so it's part of JS.

Comment: This didn't work either.

<button onclick="addToCart(\"<?php echo $productName ?>\", <?php echo $price ?>)">Add to cart</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<button  onclick="addToCart('<?=$productName?>', '<?=$price?>')">Add to cart</button>
```